# Maven Assembly Plugin and Executable jar

Tags: maven-3

I'm able to successfully build the Maven assembly plugin in my project and generate a jar file with all the needed dependencies. But now I also want to instruct Maven after building me the jar file with dependencies, go into the target folder where the jar file with dependencies is located and run my main program.

Should I consider looking into the Maven Exec Plugin for what I want to acheive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-using-plugin-dependencies.html) is the right choice. The question is if you like to start the assembled jar archive or just a java class with it's dependencies.